# ioctlsocket or recv takes more time to execute in windows socket programming?

Tags: c++, winsock

In socket programming, some data is sent to the server, and as soon as server receives it sends the acknowledgement response message. it is more than 1 byte, so i check for more than one byte check while receiving, here i am losing around 120-200ms. Which is a very big issue. As client need to send ack back for this acknowledgement. I have sniffed to see data is arrived to my IP at the same time when server has sent. but recv or ioctlsocket(to check more than 1 byte is ready to be read) takes time to read more than one byte. How can i resolve this. The code is as follows.

```
        DWORD RecvCount = 0;    
        char szBuff1[2048];         
        bool stop = false;          
        while(!stop)
        {               
            ioctlsocket(*socket, FIONREAD, &RecvCount);
            if(RecvCount > 1)
                stop = true;
        }
        int Res = recv(*socket, szBuff1, RecvCount,0);
```

Comment: You should really be using `select` instead of busy looping around `ioctl`. I suspect doing so will greatly lower your latency.

Comment: select is working, but server will give Ack and then response, everything at same millisecond,but socket is ready from select after only ack has come,i need to wait for the another response also.How do i go about this.

Comment: You can loop on reading easily enough. just repeat until you have your entire message (or time out).

Comment: It takes time to loop through.(100-200ms).which i dont want to lose. The same milisecond i am getting a response from server but not available in the socket. i have sniffed to see data is arrived to my IP.

Comment: It really shouldn't take ~200ms, if you're using blocking sockets you can just call `recv` again, which will wake up when data is available again. `select` for a single socket shouldn't take that long either (note that you don't need to zero the socket set again when you loop, just make sure your socket is in the set. which it will be if you're only checking one socket for readability)

Answer (score 2):

You should disable the Nagle algorithm on windows as otherwise the socket will sit on your data until the buffer is full (or at least wait a couple of hundred milliseconds before sending it anyway).

You do this by setting the TCP_NODELAY socket option:

```
int flag = 1;
int result = setsockopt(m_Socket,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,(char *) &flag,sizeof(int));
```

Comment: That's only relevant when sending, not receiving.